# How to Read Tensorflow 2.0 Keras API Documentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am looking at the documentation for Keras applications in TF 2.0 and I feel like I must be missing something.

The [TF 2.0 documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/ResNet101V2) for ResNet101V2, for example, is supremely unhelpful when compared to the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/applications/#resnet) of the same application. Following the TF documentation's 'View source code on GitHub' link just sends you down a rabbit hole as the documentation references a decorator. Am I using the TF documentation incorrectly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They probably just haven't got around to adding real documentation for that yet. As far as I am aware, the tf implementation should follow the keras.io documentation, so you should be able to reference stuff there.